# EPSON Printer driver for download

Tags: drivers

I have tried to find a printer driver for EPSON L360 on websites, running for Ubuntu 14.04. But I could not get one.

Answer (score 4):

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Here are the drivers from Epson. Enter L360 for model. and select Linux in the OS dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a solution to the same question and then after a little trial I could install the printer and scanner driver for Xubuntu 18.04. Here is how you can do it.

Download the Epson printer and scanner drivers from the Epson website: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Open terminal and navigate to the Downloads directory
You can try to install them with

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.6-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb  epson-printer-utility_1.1.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

If the installation fails with error listed below, that means there are dependency problems.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-escpr (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-printer-utility:
 epson-printer-utility depends on lsb (>= 3.2); however:
  Package lsb is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package epson-printer-utility (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr
 epson-printer-utility
```

Type the following commands and the drivers should get installed

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Hope this helps you and someone else looking for the solution. If it worked for you, please consider marking it useful.